# Add a class 'hidden' to my div when cookie has been set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class "hidden" to 'following_prompt' when the user has clicked to close a container. When they click to close the container a cookie is set.

MY JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // if the cookie exist, hide the element
    var hide = Cookies.getJSON('hide');

    if (hide && hide.element)
       $(hide.element).hide();

    $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         $('.following_prompt').hide()

         Cookies.set('hide', {element: '.following_prompt'}, { expires: 7 });
         return false;
         $('.following_prompt').addClass('hidden')
    });
});
```

Comment: Define your problem.

Comment: So `element.addClass('hidden')`?

Comment: Hey @Andy that could do it - i don't know much about JS. Where do I put this?

Comment: Place it after the cookie is set, as you clearly state in your question...

Comment: is following_prompt your div class?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh yes. I want to add a class 'hidden' to it after the cookie has been set. please help

Comment: Have you `console.log(hide.element)` to check it's returning `.following_prompt` if the cookie is set? Check your console for the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "chain" methods together in jQuery so I would do this:

```
$('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
     $('.following_prompt').addClass('hidden').hide();
     Cookies.set('hide', {element: '.following_prompt'}, { expires: 7 });
});
```

Note that `$('.following_prompt')` targets a *class* of element, so if you have more than one of them, they will *all* have that `hidden` class added and *all* of them will be hidden. If you need to target one element add a unique id to it and use `$('#elementid')` to target it instead.

There's no need for that `return` statement so I removed it.

Comment: Daanngg I thought that was it Andy! Unfortunately, it is not adding the class :( I thought this might be a problem lol

Comment: Hey @Andy this seems to work but when I refresh the page the class is dropped from the container? The class needs to be on there for the duration of the cookie

Comment: Well, if you refresh the page all of the elements will go back to their default state. If you want that element to remain hidden you need to write some code that looks at the cookie when the page loads and then automatically hides the element.

Answer (score 0):

The way i see your question, you want to add a class to a div. To do that simply use, $('#divId').addClass('className')

Comment: The OP is creating a cookie, once the cookie is set the `following_prompt ` element should be given a class name of `hidden`. If you want to keep this as your answer I would recommend you expand on it with more detail and complete the rest of the question.

Comment: What element do you need to hide? The one that was clicked on?

Comment: 'following_prompt' !!

Comment: @EdVinicombe Yea, that's how u put it.. Make sure you put the correct ID of the Div.

Comment: @Chandrasekar Ed Vinicombe isn't using an `ID` to target the element. It's a class name. Hence the `.` and not a `#` in front of  **following_prompt**

Comment: @NewToJS Ohk.. Sorry.. didn't see that